# Filtering users out in a journey via values housed in separate DE

Tags: journeybuilder, filters, exclusion-script, suppressionlist, cross-filter

**GOAL:** Create a API event journey that filters users out based off of values passed in the API call when compared against matching values in matching fields in a separate data extension.

I have a journey with an API entry event. In the API call, fields and values are sent that our company uses to target and differentiate groups of our users. In a separate DE, I have the same field names, and want to use the values in those fields and say if they match, then route them out of the journey. If they do not match, then continue through the journey. This would effectively allow us to filter users out for certain emails based on each level of internal targeting hierarchy in real time AND allow us to update the DE on the fly as those filtering needs change.

The data in the separate DE appears as such:

```
| Field Name 1 | Field Name 2 | Field Name 3 |         Email Name          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     null     |     12345    |     null     |      Onboarding Email 1     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     6789     |     null     |     null     |      Onboarding Email 2     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     null     |     null     |     07421    |      Onboarding Email 1     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     etc.     |      etc.    |     etc.     |             etc             |
```

Does anyone know of a way to essentially filter users out based on a matching field value that lives in a separate DE? The fundamental issues seems to be comparing user values against values in a DE, when SFMC is designed to compare user values against user values.

**PREVIOUS ATTEMPTS:** We tried linking the data extension above via data designer to Contact Data in hopes of creating a decision split that used Compared Attribute:

(Field Name 1 on the left is Contact Data, aka above data extension. Field Name 1 on the right is from Journey Data from API call)

(Field Name 1 = Field Name 1 OR
Field Name 2 = Field Name 2 OR
Field Name 3 = Field Name 3) AND
Email Name = Onboarding Email 1

This did not work because Contact Data is on a user level, and does not work as an independent value placeholder. There must be a linked data field but our values in the DE are on a grouping level, not a user level, so this does not work.

Thank you in advance for your time considering this problem!

Comment: Is this for a single entry journey where the contact only appears in your journey's data extension once?

Comment: Hi Macca! So, they enter the journey once, receive or do not receive an email, and then exit. They can re-enter as many times as they want, however, and email (and some other fields) are primary keys for that reason. They would absolutely appear in the DE more than once if they use our product with a moderate level of engagement.